# Install4j: common rollback action for multiple scripts or custom actions

Tags: java, install4j

I am implementing a silent updater where I do all the version check/ update availability check myself with custom codes and also the installation of the updater after the download. during the installation process I do backups and then perform the update installation and afterwards I perform some tests. All these are done using custom action codes and scripts.

Now for custom actions I know I can `override` the  `rollback()` method and for scripts there is this "optional Rollback Script". But is there any action/ abstract class / listener class that I can use commonly for all the codes/scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an event listener:

```
context.addInstallerEventListener(new InstallerEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void installerEvent(InstallerEvent event) {
        if (event.getType() == EventType.CANCELLING) {
            // custom rollback
        }
    }
});
```

It will be called before the actions are rolled back. To do something after the actions have been rolled back, replace `EventType.CANCELLING` with `EventType.CANCELED`.

Comment: btw just a curious ques: can I manually trigger this event from codes/scripts apart from returning false?

Comment: No, currently that is not possible.